# hadoop class path

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to run some unit tests for mapper and reducer using junit and mockito.
Do I have to specify the location of the hadoop core and commons jar files in classpath everytime I run a test?.
I thought running the "hadoop" command was supposed to automatically include all the required libraries at runtime. Is there anyway to avoid typing the hadoop dependencies everytime?.

```
hadoop -cp /home/xxx/Downloads/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar:/home/xxx/Downloads/junit-4.10.jar:/home/xxx/Downloads/hadoop-1.1.1/hadoop-core-1.1.1.jar:./classes:.:/home/xxx/Downloads/hadoop-1.1.1/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MaxTemperatureMapperTest
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the classpath in hadoop-env.sh.
"export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=*****"
The next time you run hadoop, the classpath will be automatically added.

Comment: what is the use of running the hadoop command vs Java command? what does "export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=*" do?

Comment: When you run hadoop programs, you normally use hadoop command. Of course you can check out bin/hadoop to see what the hadoop command actually does.   export is used so that it is automatically added to the classpath of the program so that you don't have to add it in the parameters  each time you run it